# How to join two select statements in one table?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql and I have two correctly working select statements with longest and shortest names. I can't really understand how can I join them in one statement. Can someone help, please.

Here are the queries:

```
SELECT name AS Country, CHAR_LENGTH(name) AS NameLength 
FROM country 
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(name) DESC, name 
LIMIT 1;

SELECT name AS Country, CHAR_LENGTH(name) AS NameLength 
FROM country 
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(name), name 
LIMIT 1;
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
Country                                        NameLength 
----------------------------------------------------------
South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands   44     
Chad                                           4     
Cuba                                           4
```

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You use UNION:

```
SELECT Country, NameLength FROM (
SELECT name AS Country, CHAR_LENGTH(name) AS NameLength FROM country LIMIT 1;
UNION
SELECT name AS Country, CHAR_LENGTH(name) AS NameLength FROM country LIMIT 1; )a
ORDER BY NameLength DESC, Country
```

Comment: Well, very nearly

Comment: Yea I just realized I misread his question editing the answer

Comment: I always like to test code before pasting it here. It avoids silliness.